# Doing IPC(Inter Process Communcation) in linux With java web service

Tags: java, linux, pipe

Say getting the output of linux program to the java web service. I know how to do it on php but how in java?..

In php i use pipes..

```
proc_open()
```

And in java what API can i use for a web service?... It's my first time in java btw.

Thanks.

Comment: Read things around this class (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Answer (score 1):

To launch a process : [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

To redirect the output stream: [Process.getOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29)

Oracle documentation of ProcessBuilder gives a full code sample.